# Can't figure out how to make code 'restart'

Tags: python-3.x

I know the line "goto Start" is wrong just put it there, that's where I want the code to loop back to the start of the code but cannot figure out how to do it at all. Please help....

```
dsides = int(input("how many sides do your dice have?"))
print("Your dice has " + str(dsides) +" sides")

dint = int(input("How many dice do you want to roll?"))
print("You are rolling " + str(dint) + " dice")

import os
answer=0
import random
y=0

while( y < dint ):
    out = random.randint(1, int(dsides))
    print(str(out))
    y=y+1



while (True):
    answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if(answer in ("y", "n")):
        if(answer == "y" ):
            goto start
        else:
            print("GoodBye")
            break
    else:
        print ("Invalid input.")
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the code in a function and call the function:

```
def my_function(output=''):  # <-- change 1

    dsides = int(input("how many sides do your dice have?"))
    print("Your dice has " + str(dsides) +" sides")
    dint = int(input("How many dice do you want to roll?"))
    import random
    y = 0
    while y < dint:
        out = random.randint(1, int(dsides))
        output += "{} ".format(out)   # <-- change 2
        # print(str(output))   # <-- change 3
        y=y+1

    while True:
        answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ("y", "n"):
            if answer == "y":
                my_function(output)  # <-- recursive call
            else:
                print(output)   # <-- change 4
                print("GoodBye")
                return
        else:
            print ("Invalid input.")
            break
```

Example output:

```
how many sides do your dice have?6
Your dice has 6 sides
How many dice do you want to roll?6
Run again? (y/n): n
2 1 3 4 6 5 
GoodBye
```

Comment: thank you, would you also have any idea on how i would have the output of the dice to look like " Roll Output : x, x, x, x, x" ?